# Gouged new wood floor with flooring sander

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I am in the middle of a DIY flooring project. I nailed down southern yellow pine and sanded it with a rental [random orbit sander](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/varathane/ezv-sander). While sanding with the final 80 grit, the sander gouged the floor in several places. It seemed to catch the wood grain at just the wrong angle, lifting and breaking a small section in the surface of the board. Each gouge is constrained to a single board in the direction of the grain. The gouges are about an inch wide and 4-6 inches long.

How should I go about repairing these? I'm considering wood filler, removing the damaged section with router and chisel and gluing in a small patch of scrap flooring, sanding away the damaged portion and just live with a divot in the floor, or replacing a section of the complete board. I intend to paint the floor once this is done, if that has any bearing.

Comment: Paint will hide the damage once repaired, so most of those repair choices should work.  Without knowing the type of room it is in(shop floor or dining room), paint might not be best choice.  If the wood floor looks nice and is in a nice room, better finishes(more work) might be better than paint.

Comment: If you decide not to paint, pulling the board and replacing it is probably your best bet. No need to pull up 1/2 the floor, though, there are decent ways of patching a solid wood floor by replacing part of only the one damaged board.